# How would you represent $y=(x-h)^2+k$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I tried using $$x=r\cos(\theta)$$ and $$y=r\sin(\theta)$$ and ended up with $r\sin(\theta) = (r\cos(\theta)-h)^2 + k$ and wasn't sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Your curve is a [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola). From this equation, find $r$ as a function $\theta$. But it's easier when $h=0$ and $-k$ is the distance from parabola vertex to focus... (then you get the usual [polar equation of a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Polar_coordinates)).

Answer (score 0):

Set $$x-h=\sqrt{k} \tan(\theta)$$
So,
$$x=h+\sqrt{k} \tan(\theta)$$

Now, $$y=k \tan^2(\theta) + k = k\,{\sec^2(\theta)} $$

Finally,
$x=h+\sqrt{k} \tan(\theta)$
and
$y=k\,{\sec^2(\theta)} $.